# Slickgrid, confirm before edit

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, editing

I am making a slick grid and need the ability to add rows with a code column. For this to be possible the code column needs to be editable for the entire table.

I am trying to work out a way that I can confirm the edit with a standard javascript confirm popup box. I tried putting one into the onedit event within the slickgrid constructor and that executed after the edit.

I am led to believe that the edit function is independent from calling the edit stored procedure of the database. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
RF_tagsTable = new IndustrialSlickGrid(
    LadlesContainerSG
    , {
        URL: Global.DALServiceURL + "CallProcedure"
    , DatabaseParameters: { Procedure: "dbo.TableRF_tags" , ConnectionStringName: Global.ConnectionStringNames.LadleTracker }
    , Title: "RF tags"
    , Attributes: {
            AllowDelete: true
        , defaultColumnWidth: 120
        , editable: true
        , enableAddRow: true
        , enableCellNavigation: true
        , enableColumnReorder: false
        , rowHeight: 25
        , autoHeight: true
        , autoEdit: false
        , forceFitColumns: true
    }
    , Events: {
        onRowEdited : rowEdited
                    /*function(){    //this is my failed attempt
                        var r=confirm("Edit an existing tag?")
                        if (r){
                            alert(r);
                        } else {
                            alert(r);
                        }
                    }*/
        , onRowAdded : rowAdded
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (you want to confirm your edit before applying your value to the grid), you should write a custom Editor for your code column.
Then you have control absolute over user input.

> You can also intercept all cell edits and have complete control over
>   how and when those edits are committed by specifying a custom handler
>   by setting the editCommandHandler grid option.

See [this](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Writing-custom-cell-editors) for further reference.

Comment: Well yes, that's what I want to do, however as I was looking into your further reference (very helpful thanks) I hot another wall. I am trying to use the approach they used for the undo, just with a confirm prompt rather than a button. This requires the option 'editCommandHandler' which is found on this list:
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options
I am using Industrial slick grid which is very similar bit it has an attributes section, not an option section and this option prevented my table from loading.

Answer (score 0):

An `editCommandHandler` is a more appropriate mechanism for this.

See http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3b-editing-with-undo.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnBeforeEdit`,

```
grid.onBeforeEditCell.subscribe(function(e,args) {
     \\if true is returned it will edit the cell othewise not
  }
});
```